# Object could not be converted to string

Tags: php

The global variable is a class (object) already defined earlier

```
class Users
{
    private $sql;

    public function __construct() {
        global $sql;
        $this->$sql = $sql;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to assign the object to a private variable in my other class (Users) so I don't have to use this line `global $sql;` through all the functions in `Users` but it's giving me this error:

`Catchable fatal error: Object of class Bdcon could not be converted to string in /home/<<NAME>>/public_html/<<NAME>>/classes/class.users.php on line 8`

Comment: You should pass `$sql` to your constructor, makes for cleaner, clearer code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (normally) use an object as property name:

```
$this->$sql
       ^
```

But you don't really want:

```
$this->sql
```

Whatever, I recommend this other style:

```
class Users
{
    private $sql;

    public function __construct(Bdcon $sql) {
        $this->sql = $sql;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't access the `private $sql` in the right way. It should be:

```
$this->sql = $sql;
```

The reason you get the error is that if you use `$this->$sql`, `$sql` is cast to a string and php tries to look for a property with the name of the value of `$sql`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->sql.` because you are accessing property of the class so no need to add $ sign instead use `$this->`